# What is the difference between split("\\W") and split("[^\\w']")

Tags: java, regex, split

What is the difference between

```
split("\\W")
```

and

```
split("[^\\w']")
```

?

Comment: @FailedDev It doesn't look very promising :D

Answer (score 12):

`\\W` is the same as `[^\\w]`, but in your case, `[\\w']` doesn't match a `'` (single quote), which `\\W` does match.

So, let's say you're trying to split the string:

```
String s = "ab'cd ef";
```

then `split("\\W")` will return: `["ab", "cd", "ef"]` and `split("[^\\w']")` returns: `["ab'cd", "ef"]`.